# Let $\{w_1, w_2,\dotsc,w_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that, for any vectors $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, orthogonality

I'm trying to prove $$u+v= (u·w_{1} + v·w_{1})w_{1} + \dotsb + (u·w_{n} + v·w_{n})w_{n}.$$

I'm not sure how to go about this problem.

Comment: any vector can be defined as a linear combination of its basis. It's orthogonal basis can be generalized in standard ordered basis of R^n or just any orthogonal basis as a product of u(w1, w2, ..., wn). use the property of linearity and axioms of vector spaces to derived the right side of u+v.

Comment: I see, so would it be u+v= w1·w1(u + v) + . . . + wn·wn(u + v) ?

Comment: that's a starting step. Keep up the good work!

Comment: would w1·w1 equate to 1?

Comment: yes, if and only if it is orthonormal. Is it orthonormal or just orthogonal?

Comment: then no, we cannot assume that w1·w1 = 1. Sorry, I haven't done this in a long while.

Comment: it's okay, I'm still trying to make sense of all this

Comment: It is a mistake to try and push the setup and statement of a problem exclusively into the title of a Question, especially if you are "still trying to make sense of all this."  The body of the Question allows you to give Readers a detailed setup and problem statement without sacrificing logical coherence.  The approaches considered and/or rejected can then supplement the problem statement in a natural (for Readers) way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(w_1,...,w_n)$ is a basis, for every $u$ there is a unique sequence $(u_1,...,u_n)$ of scalars such that $u=\sum_{i=1}^n u_iw_i.$

Since $(w_i,w_j)=0$ when $j\ne i$ we have $(u,w_j)=\sum_{i=1}^nu_i(w_i,w_j)=u_j(w_j,w_j).$

Since $w_j$ is a basis vector we have $w_j \ne 0$ so $(w_j,w_j)\ne 0.$ So $(u,w_j)=u_j(w_j,w_j)\implies u_j=\frac {(u,w_j)}{(w_j,w_j)}.$

As this is for every $j,$ we have $u=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac {(u,w_j)}{(w_j,w_j)}w_j.$

The formula in your Q, when $u=w_i$ (for any $i$) and $v=0,$ is $w_i=\sum_{j=1}^n(w_i,w_j)w_j=(w_i,w_i)w_i.$  This is false unless  $(w_i,w_i)=1$   because $w_i\ne 0$.

If $(w_1,...,w_n)$ is an orthonormal basis then $u=\sum_iu_iw_i=\sum_i\frac {(u,w_i)}{(w_i,w_i)}w_i=\sum_i(u,w_i)w_i,$ with a corresponding formula for $v,$ and the sum of these formulae is $u+v.$